# remove disabled didn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have some script from php loop

```
<?php
for($y=1;$y<=5;$y++){
echo"
<script>
 function check_$y(val)
{       
    if(val == '3'){
        document.getElementById('sbg_$y').disabled=false; 
    }else{
        document.getElementById('sbg_$y').disabled=true;
    }
}
</script>




<select name='as_$y' id='c_$y' onchange='check_$y(this.value)'>
   <option value='talent'>talent</option>
   <option value='produser'>produser</option>
   <option value='writer'>penulis</option>
   <option value='actor'>actor</option>
</select>       

<input size='20' id='sbg_$y' type='text' name='sebagai_$y' disabled>

";//end of echo



}//end of loop

?>
```

i want if actor selected `id='sbg_$x'` is enable, but i don't know why that function isn't work i guess it caused by php loop,

anyone can solve it ? i'm new in javascript

Comment: your check function is checking against the value 3, but your select values are all text

Comment: have you tried using the browser's inspector? firebug or anything, you can debug that by yourself, i'm sure you learn a few things too

Answer (score 0):

You have given all values as texts...so you have to match with text

Do it like this...

```
function check_$y(val){    
     if(val == 'actor'){
         document.getElementById('sbg_$y').disabled=false; 
     }else{
         document.getElementById('sbg_$y').disabled=true;
     }
}
```

or you can match the selected index...

```
<select name='as_$y' id='c_$y' onchange='check_$y(this)'>
   <option value='talent'>talent</option>
   <option value='produser'>produser</option>
   <option value='writer'>penulis</option>
   <option value='actor'>actor</option>
</select>

function check_$y(selectBox){    
     if(selectBox.selectedIndex == '3'){
         document.getElementById('sbg_$y').disabled=false; 
     }else{
         document.getElementById('sbg_$y').disabled=true;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**you have to put script before the loop. And check value equals your option value
not number**

```
<script>
 function check_$y(val)
{       
    if(val == 'actor'){
        document.getElementById('sbg_$y').disabled=false; 
    }else{
        document.getElementById('sbg_$y').disabled=true;
    }
}
</script>
```

Then Start loop

```
<?php

for($y=1;$y<=5;$y++){
<select name='as_$y' id='c_$y' onchange='check_$y(this.value)'>
   <option value='talent'>talent</option>
   <option value='produser'>produser</option>
   <option value='writer'>penulis</option>
   <option value='actor'>actor</option>
</select>       

<input size='20' id='sbg_$y' type='text' name='sebagai_$y' disabled>

";//end of echo
}
?>

}
```